# Mendeley Bibliography Settings

Tags: citations

I'm trying to format my bibliography in Mendeley. Specifically, I'd like it to have this format (in a single document):

Text 1

References for text 1 (1, 2, 3)

Text 2

References for text 2 (4, 5, 6).

How can I do this using the Mendeley cite plug-in for word? Essentially I want to split the bibliography in two.
Thanks!